# Unable to start program ATL Project C++

Tags: c++, atl, bho

I am trying to create a BHO with the ATL Project in Visual Studio 2010. I have been following this article:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The project builds successfully however I get an error popup with an ambiguous "Unable to start program 'C:\ .... MyProject.dll'"

My BHO just has the bare bones code, I've only added what was mentioned in the article until it says to build for the first time so most of it is auto generated. Anyone run into this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run Dll directly. Set "Executable for Debug Session" as described in the article:

"Start the debugger by pressing F5. When the Executable for Debug Session dialog box appears, select the "Default Web Browser" and click OK. If Internet Explorer is not your default browser, you can browse for the executable. "

Edit: Project - Properties - Configuration Properties - Debugging - Command. Type here executable name which works with the library.

Comment: thanks for the response and sorry for being a noob :) is there a way to set it to open in the browser manually from options and settings? i am not getting this dialog box, only the error.

Comment: thanks so much! i just set it to be my internet explorer exe and it did open, after which it asked if i wanted to enable my add on. hope that was right. thanks again for the help.